# Asking some other function call a function, but who provided the argument value?

Tags: swift, function

The code is silly simple. There is a button in the view, during run time when user taps the button, the button will move 20 point downwards.

the the viewController has a IBOutlet and a IBAction, both of them are connected to the button in the interface builder

Here comes the code of the viewControleller

```
class viewController : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func moveMyButton(_ sender: Any) {

        func whatToAnimate() {
            self.myButton.frame.origin.y += 20
        }

        func whatToDoLater(finished: Bool){
            print("finished: \(finished)") //who passed the "true" value to the finished variable
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, 
                    animations: whatToAnimate, 
                    completion: whatToDoLater)
    }

}
```

When ***animate*** function has been called in the run time, the function ***whatToDoLater() -> void*** was passed into the ***animate*** method as a argument.

The string "finished: true" prints in the console when user taps the button

**Question** :

Who passed the Boolean value "true" to the whatToDoLater function's argument **finished**? I think I didn't do that. What's the mechanism behind it?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIView animate` method passes the parameter since it is what calls the completion handler.

This pattern is seen with any use of a completion handler. Whatever actually calls the completion handler is also responsible for passing the proper parameter values to the completion handler.